# CSS Grid layout text overlap issue where grid-row-start value is more then 1000

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, css-grid

I am trying to render a CSS grid layout in which controls(textbox, labels etc) are distributed across various pages(pagination) on web app.

Our application structure is such that we get the grid-row-start values from the server(it is configured in some other system) which defines where the controls should render on web on particular page.

We don't actually render more 200-300 rows at a time on particular page, but since the grid-row-start value comes from server its possible values can be more then 1000 as it is assigned in some other system.

We can't overwrite the grid-row-start values as to some arbitrary integer values because it wont render the controls as defined in some other system.

Below example is of page number 3 on my web application, in which grid-row-start starts will number 100 but in actual it is the first row on the page.

```
 <div style="grid-area: 1000 / 1 / span 1 / span 20;">
       <div>Test div row start 1002 <!-- row start value from server --></div>
    </div>
    <div style="grid-area: 1000 / 1 / span 1 / span 20;">
       <div>Test div row start 1003 <!-- row start value from server --></div>
    </div>
   <div style="grid-area: 1000 / 1 / span 1 / span 20;">
   <div>Test div 1004 row start <!-- row start value from server --></div>
   </div>
```

PS: I know that chrome has a limit due to which it restricts not more then 1000 rows but in actual i dont have more then 1000 rows.